Poker: Proof that running the deck multiples times from Turn to River doesn't change EV. How do you prove the same but for Flop to River instead?
There's this scenario that occurs in Texas hold 'em poker where two players will be all-in before the river card is dealt, and they agree to "run it twice". We'll start with the simplest case, where this happens where two players are all-in on the turn.
When two players are all-in on the turn what "running it twice" means is that the final river card will be dealt two times to generate two different boards, and the pot is split in direct proportion to the number of boards you win. If you win both boards, you win the whole pot. If you win one board and lose the other board, you win half of the pot. If you lose on both boards, you win nothing.
Similarly, if you agreed to run it "three times" from turn to river, the pot would be split into thirds. Running it "q times" would split the pot into 1/q * P fragments, where "P" denotes the size of the pot.
Proof that running it multiple times from turn to river doesn't change EV
Let's label the players in the hand by "Player 1" and "Player 2", and we'll be calculating Player 1's EV specifically.
They decide to run the river card "q times", where 1 ≤ q≤ N, and N represents the number of cards left in the deck for them to use.
We will create a function, EV(q), which is the EV of player 1 if they run the turn to river card q times. It will be shown at the end the final expression is independent of q, i.e. running it multiple times doesn't matter.
The pot is size "P" after all players go all-in on the turn. The pot is split between the players in proportion to the number of runouts out of q they win.
If player 1 wins "x" out of q runouts , they win x/q of the total pot P, and will hence win x/q * P. So let's make "x" as a variable which denotes the number of runouts that player 1 wins out of q runouts.
Let "k" denote the number of cards in the deck out of N cards for which if they are dealt on the river, player 1 will win that board.
If "k" denotes the number of cards in the N card deck remaining that player 1 will win if they arrive on the river, then "N-k" denotes the numbers of cards on the river for which player 2 will win that runout if that card appears.
For the of simplicity, I've assumed that there's no chop outs. I.e. in other words, there's a binary choice where each card in the N-card deck either makes player 1 win or it will make player 2 win. (this allows us to use a hypergeometric distribution)
As you run the river card multiple times, the N-card deck gets depleted by 1 unit after every singular runout.
Constructing a probability function
Before calculating the EV of running the deck q times, the first step is to create a multivariable probability function " f(N,q,k,x)" which denotes the probability that player 1 will win x out of q run-outs.
The most compact form to write this function in on the end takes the form of what's called a "hypergeometric distribution". This proof uses standard theory related to that, where you end up taking the mean of this function later on.
$$ \begin{align*}
f(N,q,k,x) &= \binom{q}{x} \times \frac{ \frac{k!}{(k-x)!} \times \frac{(N-k)!}{(N-k-q+x)!}}{\frac{N!}{(N-q)!}} \\ 
 &= \frac{q!}{x!(q-x)!} \times \frac{ \frac{k!}{(k-x)!} \times \frac{(N-k)!}{(N-k-q+x)!}}{\frac{N!}{(N-q)!}}  \\
&= \frac{ \frac{k!}{x!(k-x)!} \times \frac{(N-k)!}{(q-x)!(N-k-q+x)!}}{\frac{N!}{q!(N-q)!}} \\
f(N,q,k,x) &= \frac{ \binom{k}{x} \times \binom{N-k}{q-x}}{ \binom{N}{q}} \\
\end{align*} $$
By definition, $ \sum \limits_{x=0}^{q} f(N,q,k,x) = 1 $, because the sum of all probabilities is 1. This result will be used later on when taking the mean of this function.
Calculating EV
From this we now get that the EV of running the deck q times from turn to river for Player 1 is $$ EV(q) =  \sum \limits_{x=0}^{q} f(N,q,k,x) \times \frac{x}{q} \times P $$ , where there's a summation over the possibilities of winning 0 runouts to winning all q runouts. And $ \frac{x}{q} \times P $ represents the amount of money won if x out of q runouts are won.
$$\begin{align*}
EV(q) &= \sum \limits_{x=0}^{q} f(N,q,k,x) \times \frac{x}{q} \times P \\
EV(q) &= \frac{P}{q} \sum \limits_{x=0}^{q} f(N,q,k,x) \times x 
\end{align*} $$
To calculate EV, the summation to workout now is the mean of a hypergeometric distribution, which is in standard theory.
$$ \begin{align*}
\sum \limits_{x=0}^{q} f(N,q,k,x) \times x &= \sum\limits_{x=1}^{q} \frac{ \frac{xk}{x} \binom{k-1}{x-1} \binom{N-k}{q-x}}{\frac{N}{q} \binom{N-1}{q-1}} \\
&= \sum\limits_{x=1}^{q} \frac{ k \binom{k-1}{x-1} \binom{N-k}{q-x}}{\frac{N}{q} \binom{N-1}{q-1}} \\
&= \frac{kq}{N} \sum\limits_{x=1}^{q} \frac{\binom{k-1}{x-1} \binom{N-k}{q-x}}{\binom{N-1}{q-1}} 
\end{align*} $$
In the first equality, you can change the index of summation from (x=0 to x=q) to (x=1 to x=q) instead. Why? Because when x=0, the whole thing is multiplied by 0, and hence it can be removed from the sum.
And also in the first equality above, the property $ \binom{n}{r} = \frac{n}{r} \binom{n-1}{r-1} $ is used.
And now from that, we can substitute dummy variables to show that a new hypergeometric distribution has been generated.
Set x-1=y, k-1=M, N-1=R, q-1=S, which means S-y=q-x and N-k=R-M
$$ \begin{align*}
\sum \limits_{x=0}^{q} f(N,q,k,x) \times x &= \frac{kq}{N} \sum\limits_{x=1}^{q} \frac{\binom{k-1}{x-1} \binom{N-k}{q-x}}{\binom{N-1}{q-1}} \\
&= \frac{kq}{N} \sum \limits_{y=0}^{S} \frac{ \binom{M}{y} \binom{R-M}{S-y}}{\binom{R}{y}} \\
&= \frac{kq}{N} \times 1 \\
\sum \limits_{x=0}^{q} f(N,q,k,x) \times x &= \frac{kq}{N} 
\end{align*} $$
Therefore, the EV of running the deck q times from turn to river for Player 1 is
$$ \begin{align*}
EV(q) &=  \sum \limits_{x=0}^{q} f(N,q,k,x) \times \frac{x}{q} \times P \\
&= \frac{P}{q} \sum \limits_{x=0}^{q} f(N,q,k,x) \times x \\
&= \frac{P}{q} \times \frac{kq}{N} \\
EV(q) &=\frac{k}{N} \times P
\end{align*} $$
Proof done
But how would one go about proving that the EV is unchanged when running the flop --> river multiples times?
This means that instead of only the fifth card on the board being ran multiples times, the fourth card and fifth card in combination are ran multiple times in a row from the deck of N cards.
It becomes a lot more complicated to calculate expected profit, because sometimes the turn card and river card work in combination work together to produce a winning hand for a player.
In a hypergeometric distribution, a singular card is always good for you or a singular card is always bad for you. This works for turn to river, where only 1 card peels off to finish the board. But this distribution doesn't work for the more complicated case of running flop to river multiple times .
If you run it from flop to river multiple times, there's two cards in combination working together. Often times no singular card is good or bad for you, its the combination of two cards from a "fixed resource" (the deck) that counts as a success or failure. (specific examples include things like "backdoor draws", or maybe you hit one of your outs on the turn but you don't win because your opponent hits a river card which makes them win)
I'm assuming that the EV is unchanged from running the flop --> river multiples times, I just don't know why or where the proof is.
I don't know why EV is unchanged, but have vague intuitions from what often happens in other probability scenarios. When one event fails for a desired outcome, that outcome becomes more likely to happen in the next event. And then when you analyse the entire tree, it all balances out by symmetries and terms cancelling out in the numerator and denominator, to give you a final figure which matches the probability of the event occurring at the first available opportunity, etc.
I've tried using set theory ideas but I can't come up with anything close to tangible for a proof [after you win or lose one runout, it isn't simple to calculate your equity on the next runout because $\binom{N-2}{2}$ is very different to $\binom{N}{2}$ . You can't precisely define how many turn + river combos in the next runout will mean you win when you compare it to how many turn + river combos meant you would win in the previous runout]
Using some set theory notation I've written out and defined some of what's tricky about the proof, but don't know how to actually do the proof for EV being unchanged running it multiple times flop-->river. But I am working on it.

I suspect there is a quicker way using linearity of expectation: once the hand is all in, the players can do nothing to affect the expected value of the outcome (no more bets, no folding).  So each "run" has the same expected value as a single "run" would have done (divided by the number of runs), and thus the overall expected value is unaffected by the number of "runs".

@Henry That's what I'm hoping for too, and I've heard people say this, I've just never seen anything formal written about this. And if you do raw computation, flop to river is very complicated with combinations compared to turn to river, hence the latter can be proved easily

I think @Henry is right, and there is nothing particularly formal to explain than linearity of expectation. Consider this version of the game: The turn and river cards are dealt $d$ times, but only the $i$-th runout counts. The expected value $E$ of a hand cannot depend on $i$. (Analogy: The chance that the top card of a shuffled deck is an ace is the same as the chance that the 4th card is an ace.) So the expected value of your game is $d(E/d)$ by the linearity of expectation. (The fact that your calculation was complicated is not surprising. The linearity of expectation is a powerful tool!)

@SteveKass I'll look into theory around EV formally and read about these proofs regarding linearity of expectation. Seems like the proof be a lot simpler than I thought it would be by reformulating the problem with standard theory I haven't seen seen yet

Alternate perspective:
You bet $~1\$~$ that a card drawn at random from the deck will be an Ace.
If you win, you get your $~1\$~$ back plus an additional $~12\$~$ back, so it is a completely fair game.
You decide to (for example) run it $~5~$ times, so you are actually betting a total of $~5\$,~$ which is $~1\$~$ each on the outcome of each of the first $~5~$ cards drawn from the deck.
Note that since (for example) the outcome of the 1st, 2nd, 4th, and 5th cards are initially unknown, the probability that the 3rd card is an Ace is exactly $~(1/13).$

So, I believe that the problem can be resolved without any consideration of linearity of expectation.
That is, when you (for example) run it twice, since the outcome of the 1st run is initially unknown, the probability of success on the 2nd run must be exactly the same as the probability of success on the 1st run.
Similarly, if you run it $~n~$ times, since the outcome of each of these runs is initially unknown, the probability of success on the $~k$-th run where $~k \in \{1,2,\cdots,n\},~$ must exactly match the probability of success on the 1st run.
So, it is as if, instead of betting $~10\$~$ that a single coin flip will come up Heads, you are (for example) betting $~1\$~$ each on the outcome of $~10~$ separate coin flips.
